# Help with symmetrize

Tags: mirror

I put the origin of the arm object at the 3D Cursor and was in the middle similarly to the other objects, so I used symmetry and now the mirrored object is at an unrelated place. What is this problem and how do I solve it?

Image below shows the problem:

[image]

Comment: try to apply scale rotation and location to all your meshes

Comment: Apply all Transforms solved my problem, thanks